# Which drawing represents an AC generator?

Tags: generator

[image]

This was a problem in my text book, and it says: "A magnet bar has been installed in the vertical rotation axis of a coil. Which of the above drawings represents an AC generator?"
Ok, the answer to this question is drawing (a), but I really don't understand it, could anyone clarify it for me? I think that we need to apply Fleming's right hand rule, but in that rule the coil is in motion and in this problem the magnet is in motion, so, I don't know exactly how to apply it here and understand the drawings.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any difference between a and b.  C, though, will not be as efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the rotating vertical magnetic AC flux is moving around horizontal axis rotor.

So (a) describes this function.

Comment: (b) is an AC generator too.

Comment: yes but not in vertical axis of rotating field

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, could you please explain the part of "vertical axis of rotating field" more?

Comment: mechanical shaft rotating is horizontal plane and thus magnets are rotating vertical so N-S magnets change flux in windings from vertical rotation axis of magnetic field then apply Fleming's rule for current direction.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, I don't get the difference. B is just A turned through 90 degrees around the vertical axis of the coil. Both are equivalent generators.

Comment: The question was specific about vertical motion of coil about a fixed magnet.  trick question. same generator.  It applies to moving coil or magnet.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, look closer... Question is *"Which of the above drawings represents an AC generator?"* I think they meant to have the magnet rotating along its length in image b), i.e. the magnet bar the same orientation as image a).

Comment: yes but OP says "it says: "A magnet bar has been installed in the vertical rotation axis of a coil"

Comment: I know, but that's just misleading to the actual question. The vertical axis of the coil is the same in A) and B). Though it's not drawn vertical here which is confusing to say the least. Vertical axis of the coil in that drawing is the X axis.

Comment: no b) has a V shaft so H rotation. tricky

Comment: Hmm... I know what you are saying, but as drawn, the answer to "Which of the above drawings represents an AC generator?" is still A and B unless something else is going on here that we are not aware of, or B is a really bad drawing.

Comment: If it had asked "Which of the above drawings represents THE AC generator?" maybe... but even then I would have said B since that's the only one with a vertical rotation axis...

Comment: "vertical rotation axis of a coil(and V magnet orientation)" only applies to a)

Comment: lol... I guess we just have to agree that our interpretation of the question is different. Bottom line if I built both, and shuffled them, and handed you them, you could not tell which was which. Anyhow. Have a great day :).

Comment: It's a question based upon semantics, rather than theory.  The answer is right because the magnet is vertical.  Lame.

Comment: trick question about orientation of magnetic field and in reality is very important when laying out RF chokes on dual TV converter boards. or magnetic coupling of current and sense cables, such as I have for 100kA welder or even stepper motor and remote sensors on I2C. or antenna polarization, so it CAN be relevant.

Comment: I have a feeling there is more to this we are missing though.  The diagrams imply the magnet is rotating, but the question indicates the coil is also rotating. A) would be your regular generator. C) wont do anything. B) would only generate if magnet RPM <> Coil RPM.

Comment: No @Trevor . Pls look again. The Coil is a square loop that rotates around a fixed magnet as described. One cannot see the whole question without the words and not just the title or photo.